# SignalR cpu and memory efficiency

Tags: .net, signalr

How many concurrent users can a server with 8GB of memory and 3GHz of CPU handle if they are using SignalR to chat each other in a single chat room?

Comment: Depends on what else are you doing in your application. For example if you store a lot of data in the session, it would comsume a lot of memory... i doubt that you will get a finite answer to your question. Anyway +1 cause its interesting.

Comment: Depends also on how many messages are you sending, how big they are, how many groups you have etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a testing tool like "crank" to see how your particular setup performs. There are too many variables to give any finite answer as pointed out.

I believe Damian Edwards and David Fowler have done testing to get up to 150k plus connections on a single VM, but that's just a stress test and may not provide your answers. As I recall it was a very tweaked setup to do that.

(posting links for reference only)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-connection-density-testing-with-crank

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank